# Computing the likelihood for multiplicative error in the independent variable

Tags: regression, predictor

A problem has recently arisen for me which involves estimating relative strength of various mechanisms contributing to an overall quantity. These strength parameters $q_j$, $j\in[M]$ stays fixed between observations of the quantity $\kappa_i$, $i\in[N]$, but the weighting factors $p_{ij}$ change between observations. These weights are not observed directly, but are simulated. The dominant source of error in the whole process is in the simulations of the weight, and unfortunately the error here is not uniform AWGN, but "in the exponent", i.e. $p_{ij}=e^{\mu_{ij} + \delta_{ij}}$. Accordingly I think I have the following model
\[\kappa_i = \sum_{j=1}^M q_j p_{ij} \epsilon_{ij}\]
\[\log(\epsilon_{ij})\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) \]
Given that I want to find an 'optimal' assignment for $\vec{q}$, I write the likelihood function
\[\log\mathcal{L}(\vec{q}) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log\left(\int\bigg(\prod_{j=1}^M d\epsilon_{ij} P(\epsilon_{ij})\bigg)\delta\left(\kappa_i-\Sigma_jq_jp_{ij}\epsilon_{ij}\right)\right) \]
Unfortunately, my attempts at putting this in a useful form haven't yielded results, and I can't seem to find any (readable to a non-professional statistician) references for this type of problem. I think it might be a good start to replace the log-normal with a more tractable gamma distribution.

Any suggestions? I would like to know if there is perhaps some way of transforming this problem so it is amenable to usual techniques. I don't need an analytic solution, but without a likelihood function I'm not sure how I'd even do it numerically.